# differential equation $(x^4+x+y)dx-xdy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have proplem
$$(x^4+x+y)dx-xdy=0$$

I have been doing so:

$$z=y/x$$

$$x\cdot(dz)/(dy)=dy/dx-z$$

$$x\cdot(dz)/(dy)=-((x^4+x+y)/(-x))-z=-1-x^3-z+z$$

$$x(dz)/(dx)=-1-x^3$$

$$dz=((-1-x^3)/(x))dx$$

after integrating of both side:

$$z=-lnx-(x^3/3)+C$$

$$y/x=-lnx-(x^3/3)+C$$

$$y=-xlnx-(x^4/3)+xC$$

I don't know if this solution is right or not?

Comment: "I don't know if this solution is right or not?" Have you tried substituting the result?

Comment: Yes, when you have a homogenuse equation of form M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0 you can put z=y/x

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind if I see an equation like that is transforming it in a complete DE tbh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Multiplying the equation by $x^{-2}$ we see that$M_{y}=N_{x}$ this shows that  differential equation is complete and  we have $$\frac{x^3}{3}+\ln x-\frac{y}{x}=c$$

Comment: That's a hell of a trouble(even if you come up with $x^{-2}$ as the integrating factor intuitively). Although a correct solution, I would suggest manipulating a reverse product rule in LHS. +1 anyway.

Comment: I don't understand. what is the difference?

Comment: Yes, now I understand, you also change to exact equation. But it is same solution.

Answer (score 0):

$$(x^4+x+y)-xy'\\
=(x^4+x+(-x\ln x-x^4/3+xC))-x(-\ln x-1-4/3x^3+C)\\
=x^4+x-x\ln x-x^4/3+xC+x\ln x+x+4/3x^4-xC\\=2x^4+2x.$$
I'd say no.